# Transactional email deliverability issues to Outlook/Hotmail

Tags: email

Problem: 0 deliverability to @hotmail.com @outlook.com

Setup: Sendgrid, dedicated IP

Done: SPF and DKIM

Next steps identified:

- ask for removal from 4 blacklists where I am listed (but I have to wait for Sendgrid to act on some of them, which is getting long!)
- follow better the [CAN SPAM guidelines](https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business)

What can I do more?

Comment: Sign up for Hotmail's Junk Mail Reporting Program (JMRP). Also, email their support. Link for signed in users http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=614866

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there isn't much more you can do other than wait.

If you have been listed on 4 different blacklists, your issues won't be just with Microsoft servers, though those are the only ones you're concerned about at this time.

Sendgrid will need to go through the motions to have you removed from the blacklists.

I have encountered issues before where even after a client was removed from the blacklists they where still blocked from Microsoft servers for a while. In speaking with Microsoft support, I was told the client would remain blocked until they didn't appear on the blacklists for a defined period of time. As I recall, it was 3 months, but your situation could be different.